# Regular expression to remove unnecessary string at last

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

> Assume that we have:

1. ABC_***ANY_STRING***_DEF
2. ***ANY_STRING***
3. ***ANY_STRING***_DEF
4. ABC_CDE_***ANY_STRING***_DEF

"ABC_" or "CDE_" can be prefix or absent. In addition, "_DEF" can be postfix or absent.

> In this case, can I extract ***ANY_STRING*** (which is just any set of characters, just a string) between prefix and postfix by using one regular expression?

For example, input = "ABC_CDE_I like an apple_DEF", then output must be "I like an apple".

I tried the following code, but it does not output what I expected.

```
re.compile("(?:ABC_|CDE_)*(\S+)(?:_DEF)?")
```

or

```
re.compile("(?:ABC_|CDE_)*(\S+)(?:_DEF)*")
```

Thanks a lot in advance for your advice.

Comment: What is your goal? please provide example of both input and output

Comment: Is `ANY_STRING` a chunk of two strings that are joined with one `_`? Or can it be just `anyStrIng`? A real life example would help.

Comment: @Wiktor ANY_STRING means just any string like expressed by \S+

Comment: its too generalised to call it any string, any string can be unwanted like ABC_CDE in the end, how can one differentiate on what is required, regex is requirement specific. There has to be a pattern of some sorts eg @ or always starts with _A etc

Comment: @Tom Ron For example, input = "abc_cde_i_like_an_apple_def", then output = "i_like_an_apple"

Comment: @Inder "ABC_" or "CDE_" can be prefix, and "_DEF" can be postfix. I'd like to extract the string between prefix and postfix. But they can exist or do not exist.

Comment: That helps please add that information in the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
(?:ABC_|CDE_|^)+(\S*?)(?:_DEF|$)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/I9iCOl/1)

**Details**

- `(?:` - start of a [non-capturing group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471) that matches any of the subpatterns separated with the [alternation operator](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) `|`:

  - `ABC_` - a literal substring `ABC_`
  - `|` - or
  - `CDE_` - a literal substring `CDE_`
  - `|` - or
  - `^` - start of string
- `)+` - one or more consecutive occurrences, as many as possible (`+` is a greedy quantifier)
- `(\S*?)` - Capturing group 1: zero or more chars other than whitespace, but as few as possible due to the `*?` lazy quantifier
- `(?:_DEF|$)` - either `_DEF` or (`|`) end of string (`$`).

Comment: what does this | expression does eg in ABC_|CDE_| ??

Comment: @Inder `|` is an [**alternation operator**](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html).

Comment: @Wiktor Can I know why (?:ABC_|CDE_|^)+(\S*)(?:_DEF|$) does not work properly? Is there something in "?" keyword to make it work?

Comment: @JoontaeKim `\S*` (*0+ non-whitespace chars*) is a greedily quantified pattern and `\S` matches `_`, `D`, `E` and `F`. So, `\S*` grabs all non-whitespace chars up to the end of string here, and checks if the `(?:_DEF|$)` can match there. Yes, the `$` matches the end of string, so Group 1 holds all the text it grabbed and the regex engine returns a valid match. See [this debugger page](https://regex101.com/r/CAsHTH/2/debugger).

Comment: @Wiktor I see. "?" seems to give a chance to check "_DEF" with assumption of absence of "\S*". Thanks a lot!!

Comment: @JoontaeKim: Accept the answer if it helped you (green tick on the left).